# how to use selector similar to ng-container in angular-4.x

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-template, ng-container

I'm using angular-4.x and inside component I'm using some 'abc' Selector as below:

```
@Component({
  selector: "Abc",
  templateUrl: "Abc.html",
  styleUrls: [
    "Abc.css"
  ]
})
```

but **"Abc"** tag is present in DOM as well but I want it to behave as **"ng-container"** which only reflect **child DOM** in page not the tag itself.

Comment: Those are called [Structural Directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)

Answer (score 2):

This might or might not work for you, depending on the use-case.

Anyway, your selector doesn't have to be a **tag selector**, it could just as well be an **attribute selector**, which means that no new tag will be added in the rendered output.

So, if your component has the following metadata...

```
selector: '[abc]',
template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
styles: [`:host { background-color: red }`],
```

And you use it like this...

```
<div abc>
  <span>Hello <b>world!</b></span>
</div>
```

The rendered output would be exactly that (no `<abc>` tag added).

---

Another possible "solution" is to use ARIA to assign a role to your custom element. For example, if you want `<abc>` to be a button, you can do something like this in the class.

```
@HostBinding('role') role = 'button'
```

This means that, semantically, it's still a button, even though it's not a `<button>` element.

Again, might or might not work for your use-case but it's an idea for a workaround.

---

Otherwise, it's impossible to currently a **component** which does what you want. [**Structural directives**](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives) come in close, but then you will not be able to apply styles, because `styles` is not valid metadata for a `@Directive`.

But you can create a no-operation structural directive by injecting `ViewContainerRef` and `TemplateRef` and just instantiating the template in the `OnInit` lifecycle hook.

```
constructor(private templateRef: TempalteRef,
            vcr: ViewContainerRef) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef)
}
```

But you would still have to use it with `<ng-container>`, if you don't want a rendered element encapsulating its content. So your request "like `<ng-container>` but different isn't really cutting it in this case.

Comment: But in given scenerio `<div abc>` will be still present. I need something like replace in angular-1.x custom directive